# Generate auto incremental id with fixed length including date and time?

Tags: oracle12c

I'm using **oracle 12c**.

I need to generate a default value as a unique ID (PK) in my table.  This value should be fixed in length as 16 digits.  The format should be like '`YYYYMMDDHHmmXXXX`'.  The last part `XXXX` should be incremental from '`0001`' to '`9999`'.   Also, the `XXXX` part should reset to `0001` per minute.

How can I generate such ID?

Comment: Primary key shouldn't be alphanumeric. Use a numeric key and append the required suffix/prefix only when you're using it

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to discuss how good your primary key generation approach is, but i think this could be implemented using Triggers:

```
create table myTest
(
    id varchar2(16) primary key,
    val number
);

create index imyTest01 on mytest(substr(id, 1, 12), substr(id, 13));

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myTest_trg before insert on myTest for each row
begin
    lock table mytest in exclusive mode; --If you have concurrent Inserts
    select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHHMI')||lpad(((nvl(max(to_number(substr(id, 13))), 0))+1), 4, '0')
      into :new.id
      from myTest
     where substr(id, 1, 12) = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHHMI');
end;

--Testing:
begin
    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
        insert into mytest(val) values(i);
    end loop;
end;
```

This can also be modified to use Numbers instead of Varchar as PK. Please be also aware of performance and locking issues with this implementation.